# How to do length validation using Spark or Pandas Dataframe..One file is having data and another file is having length

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to pyspark and seeking help on doing length validation.

Data File :-

```
File 1

Name|Salary|Age|Dept
XYZ|10000|32|HR
TUV|15000|28|IT
```

File 2 (Max length for each column)

```
Name|Salary|Age|Dept
5|8|3|2
```

Need to check if length of Name in data file (file 1) is greater than 5 in (file 2) , if yes reject the entire record.
If length of salary is greater than 8, reject the entire record. Likewise, need to check for each column using Spark or Pandas DataFrame or in Python as a last option.

Note :- Don't want to hardcode the max length in code. File can have over 200 columns and record counts can be in Million.

Comment: can you please add more details like file format and sample code you tried? Assuming they are tsv file, one quick solution I see is load into PySpark df and work with columns.

Comment: Both the files are pipe delimited (I can change the length file as require). I was trying to use panda schema DF but i need to hardcode the length for all the column which i want to avoid as have over 200 columns and want to create generic frame work which can be used to validate any file against length file.